# How to paint directly on the model without image, just with two colors

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, vertex-paint

I need to find an answer to this question. I have some simple elements - sword and spear, that could be painted only with two colours. Is there any way to paint more simple, - without making "Unwarp" and without attaching an image to them - just to paint them with the panel in the right - with the surface settings? I know, that I can paint them in one colour, the whole element with this panel, but I need some parts to be in another colour. How can I do it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

edit mode,select the faces you want,and click this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to do!